# Linking documents to customer cases

Tags: webservices

I have documents attached to customer cases. In ER data model what is the relationship between case and its uploaded files. I could understand case ID is foreign key in attachments table.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_support.htm

Answer (score 0):

The CaseId is the ParentId of the Attachment. See [Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) in the Object Reference for for more details on it's fields and usage.

Comment: Thank you crmprogdev. But my question is document and case. Not case and attachment. Can you please help me understand.

Comment: I refer you to the page that follows the link you've cited in your question. Again, the Document could only be "attached" to the Case Record as an `Attachment`, unless you've changed the schema and managed to create a Related List for it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends

**Email2Case**

Attachments sent with the email are children of `EmailMessage`. `EmailMessage` is child of `Case`

**Attachments**

Files inserted by the API or via the UI as SObject `Attachment` are direct children of Case if their `ParentId` field is the `Case.Id`

**Files**

Files added via Chatter, the UI ("Files") or via the API as SObject `ContentVersion` (with auto-created parent `ContentDocument` will be found via a junction object `ContentDocumentLink` -- a junction between `Case` and `ContentDocument`